# How to navigate android xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to make my first app currently and cant find a way to navigate between forms.
I've tried  `App.Current.MainPage = new settings();` but it just comes up with an error od missing directory for `app.current`
I've also tried the one on https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/page-navigation-between-two-pages-in-xamarin-forms-using-visual-studio/ but to no avail.
this is my code for reference, i'm trying to move the user to a different part after the try in nextpress()

```
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Widget;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using Android.Views;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Android;
using Android.App.Admin;
using Android.App.Assist;


namespace serverconand
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        public static IPEndPoint ep;
        public static string target;
        public static string password;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.initialpage);
            Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            Button nextbut = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
            
            nextbut.Click += (o, e) => 
            {
                nextpress();
            };
            
        }

        private void nextpress()
        {
            
            try
            {
                password = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.passphrase).Text;
                string targetip = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.targip).Text;
                int targetport = int.Parse(FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.targport).Text);
                IPAddress broadcast = IPAddress.Parse(targetip);
                ep = new IPEndPoint(broadcast,targetport);
                
                
            }
            catch
            {
                FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView3).Text = "Incorrect input, please try again";
            }
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

.xml code

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:text="Next"
        android:layout_width="800px"
        android:layout_height="200px"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:clickable="true"/>
        
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="400px"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:id="@+id/targip"
        android:inputType="text|none"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:translationY="100px" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Public IP adress of Target"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:translationY="30px" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Port of target"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:translationY="230px" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="400px"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:id="@+id/targport"
        android:inputType="none|text"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:translationY="300px" />
    <TextView
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="500px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:translationY="800px" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Passphrase"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:translationY="430px" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="400px"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:id="@+id/passphrase"
        android:inputType="none|text"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:translationY="500px" />
    
    

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, it looks like you are using Xamarin.Android.

There are two ways of navigating to something else.

**1. Activities**

Just like your `MainActivity` you can create another `Activity` and navigate to that one using an `Intent`.

```
var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MyOtherActivity));
StartActivity(intent);
```

If you create a new `Activity` make sure you apply the `[Activity]` attribute on it, so it gets registered in your apps manifest.

**2. Fragments**

Alternatively on Android, you can get away with only one `Activity` and swap out which `Fragment` is being shown. A `Fragment` is essentially a view with some lifecycle attached.

```
var ft = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
ft.Add(containerViewId, fragment);
ft.Show(fragment);
ft.Commit();
```

Where `containerViewId` is a placeholder area for where to show the `Fragment`, this would be defined in your `Resource.Layout.initialpage`. `fragment` being your specific `Fragment`.

Up to you which route you go.

Comment: so would fragment/myotheractivity be secondpage.xml then? Sorry, im still getting used to using the new directories and how they work

Comment: Yep, a new layout and new activity or fragment

Comment: ok thanks but i'm now getting a "cannot convert from system.type to android.content.intent" error?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, its: `new Intent(this, typeof(MyOtherActivity))`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the PushAsync method? See the Microsoft Docs link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Xamarin.Forms.INavigation.PushAsync?view=xamarin-forms

await Navigation.PushAsync (settings);

Comment: His code doesn't look like xamarin.forms though

Comment: Yes his code is Xamarin.Android or Native not Xamarin.Forms